# Sliding expiration of localized ASP.NET resources

Tags: asp.net, caching, resources, localization

Assume that we have 2 sites myDomain.AU and  myDomain.RU having the same code and localized resource files *.resx and *.ru.resx. We expected that most of English users will use AU site and most of Russian users will use RU site. However if some user of AU domain will request Russian version, .Ru resources will be loaded on AU server and Russian language will be shown.

But I don’t want to keep .RU resources until recycle of the pool, but want to unload them if no one use them. So I want to have timing expiration of cached localized resources with configured time of expiration for each language.
Related question was raised at http://techsoda.wordpress.com/2008/01/04/aspnet-reset-that-resource/ and http://forums.asp.net/t/1201065.aspx/1

Rick Strahl in “Creating a Data Driven ASP.NET Localization Resource Provider and Editor”( http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwdbresourceprovider/ ) has
DbResourceConfiguration.ClearResourceCache() , that clears all cache, but not expired only.

Any suggestions, references what is the best way to implement it are welcome.

UPDATE: Rick’s comment below pointed me, that I am doing “Premature Optimization”.
Anyway it will be good to know a solution, if loading of too many resources will become a problem in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a static dictionary as the resource cache (as in Rick Strahl's sample) why not store the individual culture data in the ASP.NET cache, which implements sliding expiration out of the box?

Comment: Great and simple idea. I will try it and check any side effects.

Comment: I don't think that's such a great idea because the cache can timeout in a number of different ways besides the timeout. Memory pressure for example can cause entries to be unloaded especially big ones like a resource dictionary.

If you use resources in your app I would suggest you live with the fact that these resources will use up some memory. Unless your app is using huge amounts of resources, in the big scheme of ASP.NET memory usage, leaving resources loaded isn't going to impact your memory footprint very much.

Comment: I agree that this rarely looks like an optimal memory management strategy, but it could be relevant in the case of many _very_ rarely used cultures in the system. The automatic cleanup of the cache can also be disabled by using CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable if desired.