# How to use resource file as data source for an editable listview?

Tags: asp.net, localization, resources, resx

My client wants to take control over the text contents on the website. And he wants an interface where he can see a and edit the resource file text.

I was *successful showing the contents of resource file in my listview*. **Updating** is the place where I am **stuck**. I just don't know what to write in the updating event. does anyone know a simple method ?

[image]

```
ResourceSet rs = Resources.resfile.ResourceManager.
                     GetResourceSet(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, true, true);

protected void Page_Prerender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView1.DataSource = rs;
    ListView1.DataBind();
}
protected void ListView1_ItemCanceling(object sender, ListViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    ListView1.EditIndex = -1;
}
protected void Updating(Object sender,ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{                
}
```

---

The following code works, but it doesn't refresh after edit, it refreshes after I update something else.

```
XmlDocument loResource = new XmlDocument();
loResource.Load(Server.MapPath("/App_GlobalResources/resfile.resx"));

XmlNode loRoot = loResource.SelectSingleNode(
                            string.Format("root/data[@name='{0}']/value",e.Keys[0].ToString()));

if (loRoot != null)
{
    loRoot.InnerText = e.NewValues[1].ToString();
    loResource.Save(Server.MapPath("/App_GlobalResources/resfile.resx"));
}    
ListView1.EditIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a demo of your question and **noticed the same problem**. After googling around and reading some forum entries I stumbled accros this **[blog](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Jul/24/Resource-Unloading-in-a-custom-ASPNET-Localization-Resource-Provider)** *Rick Strahl* pointed out that:

> **Refreshing Resources**
>
> After you’ve made changes to the resources you might actually like to
>   see the new resources show up in the live user interface. [....]
>   ASP.NET’s **resource provider loads resources** and the **resources
>   are forever cached until the application shuts down**. *As far as I
>   know there’s no built-in way to release the resources*, but the data
>   provider here includes some logic for tracking each provider [...]

As I *did not want to implement a database* to store ressources that can be update I tried this very dirty little thing! Just **called Response.Redirect** and forced a complete new Page.Request from the browser. So the *server gets a new response and re-caches ressources!*

I am aware that this is no good solution but it worked for me. I **tried** to **rebind ressources**, **unloaded appDomain** and so on - **nothing worked!** I hope this answer will help you!

```
protected void ListView1_ItemUpdating(Object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string key = e.Keys[0].ToString();
    string value = e.NewValues[0].ToString();

    XmlDocument loResource = new XmlDocument();
    loResource.Load(Server.MapPath("App_GlobalResources/resFile.resx"));

    XmlNode loRoot = loResource.SelectSingleNode(
                                string.Format("root/data[@name='{0}']/value", key));

    if (loRoot != null)
    {
        loRoot.InnerText = value;
        loResource.Save(Server.MapPath("App_GlobalResources/resfile.resx"));
    }

    ListView1.EditIndex = -1;
    Response.Redirect("demo.aspx");  // that's all!!!
}
```

Comment: found this topic on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480963/sliding-expiration-of-localized-asp-net-resources

Answer (score 0):

here a code project that explains you how to update your listview:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24570/Complete-ListView-in-ASP-NET-3-5

Comment: lol.
I that was SQL datasource and was very easy. I want to edit the ResourceSet.

Comment: XmlDocument loResource = new XmlDocument();
            loResource.Load(Server.MapPath("/App_GlobalResources/resfile.resx"));


            XmlNode loRoot = loResource.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("root/data[@name='{0}']/value",e.Keys[0].ToString()));


            if (loRoot != null)
            {
                loRoot.InnerText = e.NewValues[1].ToString();
                loResource.Save(Server.MapPath("/App_GlobalResources/resfile.resx"));
            }

            ListView1.EditIndex = -1;